# Correctly source frontpage in PHP function

Tags: php

I've been making a header.php file for my website and I want the title tag of the page to change based on which page you're visiting.

It seems to work for everything but the front page!

Here's the function I wrote:

```
<?php

$directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
$components = explode('/', $path);
$first_part = $components[1];

 $title = "";
 $jumbotitle = "";
  $url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 if(strpos($url, '/') !== false){
   $title = "Home";
   $jumbotitle = "Home";
 }if(strpos($url, 'about') !== false){
   $title = "About";
   $jumbotitle = "About";
 }
 if(strpos($url, 'contact') !== false){
   $title = "Contact";
   $jumbotitle = "Contact";
 }

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to your home and echo `$url` ... whats the output?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstly `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` should be enough

```
$url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

Please show us, what is $url value now ?

Comment: No idea! My reputation is too low to vote, anyway. You solved my issue, though :)